# How to push a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Tags: ipad, abpeoplepickerview

I am having some trouble while using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.
I am developing an ipad application.
I wanted to push ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to my navigation controller hierarchy.
I know how to extract viewcontroller from  a navigation controller, it is not working with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!!!
Please help me out!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init]; picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
 [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
          nil];

Comment: [[UIViewController alloc] init]; tempViewController = picker.topViewController but it crashes when i push this tempViewController as [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempViewController animated:NO];

Answer (score 1):

You can't push a navigation controller onto an existing navigation controller stack. You can, however show it modally, using an animation to change between your app's navigation stack to the people picker one.